# Angular ngAnimate throws error

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm trying to do some animations with ngAnimate but I cannot even get started with it. The problem is when i try to add my ngAnimate dependency to the app file it throws me this error in console and my app is not working.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $$jqLiteProvider <- $$jqLite <- $animate <- $compile
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24jqLiteProvider%20%3C-%20%24%24jqLite%20%3C-%20%24animate%20%3C-%20%24compileangular.js:63 (anonymous function)angular.js:3950 (anonymous function)angular.js:4097 getServiceangular.js:3955 (anonymous function)angular.js:4097 getServiceangular.js:4129 invokeangular.js:4025 origProvider.$getangular.js:4138 invokeangular.js:3956 (anonymous function)angular.js:4097 getServiceangular.js:4129 invokeangular.js:3956 (anonymous function)angular.js:4097 getServiceangular.js:4129 invokeangular.js:1435 doBootstrapangular.js:1455 bootstrapangular.js:1349 angularInitangular.js:25912 (anonymous function)angular.js:2722 triggerangular.js:2992 eventHandler
```

But without adding the ngAnimate dependency it's working fine. Not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

This is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            controller: 'homeCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/partials/home.html'
        })
        .when('/register', {
            controller: 'regCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/partials/register.html'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            controller: 'loginCtrl',
            templateUrl: '/partials/login.html'
        }).when('/', {
            redirectTo: '/home'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/register'
        });
});
```

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Angular Tutorial</title>
</head>

<body ng-app='myApp'>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Logo</h1>
            <a href="#/home">Home</a>
            <a href="#/register">Register</a>
            <a href="#/login">Login</a>
        </header>
        <ng-view></ng-view>
    </div>

    <!-- Vendor libraries -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>

    <!-- App libraries -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my controller

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Home page"
});

app.controller('regCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Registration message";
    $scope.register = function() {
        alert($scope.fname + "\n" + $scope.lname + "\n" + $scope.email + "\n" + $scope.password);
    };
})

app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Login message";
    $scope.login = function() {
        alert($scope.myemail + "\n" + $scope.password);
    };
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you call the angular-animate.js file?

Comment: Yeah sure i did. In my html.

Comment: check back the link in your index.html, open in console click directly if the file actually redirect or not. maybe bad links.

Comment: I'm using angular version 1.3.5 and angular animate js version 1.3.6 if it is of any help.

Comment: use same version, bug can happen if diff version

Comment: Can you update the post with the script block from which you call these scripts, and preferably complete console output

Comment: I just checked from console and the file is opening without any problems.

Comment: try declare ngAnimate in controller and not on var app =

Comment: But app dependencies are added in the app module right?

Comment: Still the same error. Can't get it fixed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Solved !!

Updating my angular version to one that equals the angular animate version fixed the issue.

Comment: Yes it was! I made the both equal version and it worked.